# Parsing jsonld in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json-ld

I have a .jsonld file and i want to read and parse the data from it. Like in javascript we do JSON.parse. Is there any similar or other way to parse jsonld data in nodejs. My code snippet is:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Peter Parker",
  "jobTitle": "Spiderman",
  "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
  "url": "http://www.spiderman.com"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fs.readFile('./.jsonid', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // do whatever you want here
});
```

Use `fs` to read contents from file, and then parse or do whatever you want with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use something like `require('./data.jsonld')`, but [`require` only works on `.{js,json,node}` file extensions](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). So you have two options:

## Option 1: Rename the file extension to `*.json`, and then use `require`

*data.json*

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Peter Parker",
  "jobTitle": "Spiderman",
  "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
  "url": "http://www.spiderman.com"
}
```

*node-app.js*

```
let data = require('./data.json')
console.log(typeof data) // 'object'
```

## Option 2: Keep `*.jsonld`, read the file with `fs`, and then parse it

*data.jsonld*

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Peter Parker",
  "jobTitle": "Spiderman",
  "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
  "url": "http://www.spiderman.com"
}
```

*node-app.js ([synchronous](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/) version)*

```
const fs = require('fs')
let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.jsonld', 'utf8))
console.log(typeof data) // 'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse a jsonld file you should ideally use the jsonld parser. See https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/